# NodeRED disable palette manager

Tags: configuration, node-red

I need to deliver a NodeRED installation to a customer without the palette manager enabled. The customer should not be able to install new nodes or delete existing ones. The palette manager should not even be shown as menu entry.

I could not find such a configuration in the config files.

Is there a configuration option for disabling the palette manager?

Ff no: How could this be achieved by other means (e.g. by modifying NodeRED code - which file, which line)?

Comment: Disabling the pallet manager will not stop the user from using npm to install packages manually into the `.node-red` directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `settings.js` file, you can set the following property to disable the palette manager:

```
editorTheme: {
   palette: {
      editable: false
   }
}
```